# Measure of the numbers with length of $n$ for a nonstandard number $n$

Tags: lo.logic, measure-theory, peano-arithmetic

> Is there any nonstandard model of $PA$ with the following properties?
>
> 1. There exists a nonstandard number $n\in M$ such that $M\upharpoonright n$ is countable,
> 2. Let $|x|=\lceil\log_2x\rceil$, then $|\{x\in M: M\models |x|=n\}|=|\mathbb{R}|=\aleph_1$, (with assumtion CH or any other axiom that implies $|\mathbb{R}|=\aleph_1$)

If the above question has a positive answer, what can be said about the measure of the numbers with length of $n$?

More precisely, let $f:\mathbb{N}\to M\upharpoonright n$ be a one to one function.

> Q1. Is set $A_f=\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-i-1}\cdot (v)_{f(i)}:v\in M,M\models|v|=n\}$ measurable? ($(x)_i$ is the i'th bit of $x$ in the binary representation)
>
> Q2. Is there any one to one function $g:\mathbb{N}\to M\upharpoonright n$ such that $A_g$ becomes measure one?

Comment: Please define what $|x|$ and $M|_n$ mean.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I understood $M\vert_n=M\upharpoonright n$ to be the initial segment of $M$ up to $n$. As to $\vert x\vert$, I think that's $log(x)$ (= the length of $x$'s representation in base $2$)

Comment: If my interpretation is right, the first part just boils down to "Is there an $M\models PA$ and an $n\in M$ with $M\upharpoonright n$ countable but $M\upharpoonright 2^n$ uncountable?" If I recall correctly, the answer to that is **yes**.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: The definition is added.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Your interpretation is right. How can such a model be constructed?

Comment: The existence of such a model follows from Vaught's two cardinal theorem. The tricky part is showing that the relevant kind of Vaightian pair exists, i.e. a proper elementary pair $M \prec N$ and a nonstandard $n$ such that $M$ and $N$ agree up to $n$, but disagree before $2^n$. You can show that this happens with exercise 7 in section 12.1 of Hodges' big model theory textbook. In fact there is nothing special about $2^n$, you can do this with any function definable in $PA$ with superpolynomial growth.

Comment: @JamesHanson: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: @JamesHanson Why not make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 7):

As requested this is a slightly more detailed answer to your first question. I really don't know how to approach your second question.

By a mild variation Vaught's two cardinal to get a model $N$ of $PA$ with a non-standard number $n$ such that $|\{x\in N:x \leq n \}|=\aleph_0$ but $|\{x\in N : x\leq 2^n\}|=\aleph_1$ it's enough to find an elementary pair of models $M \prec N$ and a non-standard number $n\in M$ such that $\{x\in M : x\leq n\}=\{x\in N : x\leq n\}$ but such that $\{x\in M: x \leq 2^n \}$ is a proper subset of $\{x \in N : x\leq 2^n \}$.

Choose a constant $n$ and add it to the language of $PA$. Now assume for the sake of contradiction that in every model $N$ of $PA$ for any $n\in N$ if $\{x\in N:x \leq n \}$ is infinite, then $|\{x\in N:x \leq n \}|=|\{x\in N : x\leq 2^n\}|$. Then by theorem 12.1.5 in Hodges' big model theory textbook there must be a layering of the definable set $\{x\in N : x\leq 2^n\}$ by the definable set $\{x\in N:x \leq n \}$ which by exercise 7 in section 12.1 implies that there is some polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients such that for any model $M$ of $PA$ (with the constant $n$) if $|\{x\in N:x \leq n \}|=m<\omega$, then $|\{x\in N : x\leq 2^n\}| \leq p(m)$, but this is clearly absurd since $2^n$ grows faster than any polynomial.

Therefore no such layering can exist and there must be a model $N$ of $PA$ with the constant $n$ such that $|\{x\in N:x \leq n \}|$ and $|\{x\in N : x\leq 2^n\}|$ are both infinite and $|\{x\in N:x \leq n \}| < |\{x\in N : x\leq 2^n\}|$. So by the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem there is an elementary substructure $M$ of $N$ such that $\{x\in N:x \leq n \} \subseteq M$ and $|\{x\in N:x \leq n \}|=|M|$, so that in particular $\{x\in N : x\leq 2^n\}$ is not a subset of $M$.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

- The point of this note is to point out that "Uncountable" can be strenghtened to "continuum-many" in Hanson's answer, but first a notation: Given a model $M$ of arithmetic and $a \in M$, I will use $[a]_M$ to denote the set $\{x\in M: x \leq a\}$.

> Theorem (Mills and Paris) There is a model of arithmetic $M$ and some $n\in M$ such that $[n]_M$ is countable but $[2^n]_M$ is of the same cardinality as $\Bbb{R}$.

More detail: Mills and Paris showed---without the use of the continuum hypothesis---that given any countable model $M_0$ of PA, and any any nonstandard $n \in M_0$, there an elementary extension $M$ of $M_0$ such that $[n]_{M_{0}} = [n]_M$ but $[2^n]_M$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_{0}}$.  This result appears in their paper *Closure properties of countable nonstandard integers,* **Fund. Math.** 103 (3) (1979) 205–215. An exposition of this result can also be found in Section 3.5 of the book **Structure of Models of Peano Arithmetic** by Kossak and Schmerl.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.